# Push/Pull elements from their grid containers

Tags: css, singularitygs

Is it possible to pull elements from their containers, while keeping them aligned with the main grid?

In the image bellow, I have a representation of what im trying to achieve. Lets say all my text, including the smaller details in the first column, are on a container which spans columns 2 and 3. Then, I want the smaller text to pull from that container one column to the left, effectively moving to column 1, while keeping alignment with the lead copy.

The red boxes are the main grid, the blue would be inner container elements.

Is this possible with Singularity?

[image: Push/Pull grid elements]

Comment: You have to think in a different way, in such situation, i would simply have 1 container that contains all the text, and then add some vertical divs with position absolute or fixed, that has a color with opacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is entirely possible with Singularity!

To pull the element out of its container just use a negative margin. But proper width and margin sizes require some tricky math:

```
<div id=container>
  <div id=a>a</div>
  <div id=b>b</div>
  <div id=c>c</div>
</div>
```

```c
$grids: 1 2 2
$gutters: .25


#container
  +grid-span(2,2)

#b
  $coefficient: (1 + 2 + 2) / (2 + 2)
  $width: column-span(1, 1) * $coefficient
  $gutter: gutter-span() * $coefficient

  width: $width
  margin-left: 0 - $width - $gutter

  float: left
  clear: both

+layout(2 2)
  #a, #c
    +grid-span(2, 1)
```

Result:

[image]

Demo: http://sassbin.com/gist/6953993/

Note that the width and position of the pulled column do not match the grid perfectly. This might be due to rounding errors in browsers, or my math might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Not in its current form, although for now you might find this useful: https://github.com/Team-Sass/toolkit#nested-context

Comment: While this requires an extra container, to be able to pass the right context to the nested-context mixin, im seeing very solid results with this technique.